# NSInvalidArgumentException error with NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to create an array of a CoreData entity to pass to another file to save to CoreData, but I am getting this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Modifier setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002587f40'`. When I add context to the initializer it runs, but I do not want to add context until it has to be saved into CoreData, why am I getting this error?

[image]

```
var modifiers = [Modifier]()
                for mod in modSnap {
                    let modifierType = mod.childSnapshot(forPath: "type").value as! String
                    let cdMod = Modifier()                    
                    cdMod.id = mod.key
                    cdMod.modType = modifierType
                    modifiers.append(cdMod)
                }
                DataController.shared.saveRemoteModifiers(modifiers: modifiers)
```

Comment: You cannot use the bare init to instantiate managed objects.  This typically gives a different error from the one you are getting.  But either way you will need to rethink.  You must use the [designated initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506357-init).

Comment: I could have sworn I've used managed objects without context in past projects, but I guess not, oh well